# Address field doesn't show in new rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a program to keep a client database for my first Rails app. I've followed through several different tutorials and successfully built out the demo apps, but now I am trying to create my own. In an effort to keep the database organized and efficient at scale, I setup a relational database with foreign keys.

My new client form should be displaying three fields - First Name, Address ID and Street, but it is only showing the first two. I've run across a couple things suggesting using .build to initialize my street field, but adding @client.address.build to def new in my clients_controller.rb didn't help. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141120045947) do

  create_table "addresses", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "number"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "street"
  end

  create_table "clients", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.integer  "address_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "street_id"
  end

  add_index "clients", ["address_id"], name: "index_clients_on_address_id", using: :btree

end
```

Form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <% if @client.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this client from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address_id, "Address ID"%><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address_id %>
  </div>
<%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= address.label :street %><br>
    <%= address.text_field :street %>
  </div>
<% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Clients controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /clients
  # GET /clients.json
  def index
    @clients = Client.all
  end

  # GET /clients/1
  # GET /clients/1.json
  def show
    @address = Address.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /clients/new
  def new
    @client = Client.new
  end

  # GET /clients/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /clients
  # POST /clients.json
  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /clients/1
  # PATCH/PUT /clients/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.update(client_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /clients/1
  # DELETE /clients/1.json
  def destroy
    @client.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to clients_url, notice: 'Client was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_client
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def client_params
      params.require(:client).permit(:first_name, :address_id, address_attributes: [:number,:street])
    end
end
```

Addresses controller:

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_address, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /addresses
  # GET /addresses.json
  def index
    @addresses = Address.all
  end

  # GET /addresses/1
  # GET /addresses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /addresses/new
  def new
    @address = Address.new
  end

  # GET /addresses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /addresses
  # POST /addresses.json
  def create
    @address = Address.new(address_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.save
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @address }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /addresses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /addresses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.update(address_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @address }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /addresses/1
  # DELETE /addresses/1.json
  def destroy
    @address.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to addresses_url, notice: 'Address was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_address
      @address = Address.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def address_params
      params.require(:address).permit(:number, :street)
    end
end
```

Client model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
end
```

Comment: Should `show` in `ClientsController` be `@client = Client.find(params[:id])` instead of `@address = Address.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want here, do you want one client to have many addresses? If so then you need client_id in address, not address_id in client. Also why is there a street_id in client? Also, post your model for client and address so we know more about the relationship between them.

Comment: @UriAgassi - yes it should be, I'm not sure why I had that switched around...probably got changed when I was experimenting with some possible solutions and I didn't change it back. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: amunds - I have added the two models, I'm sorry I forgot to add them last night. The reason why it seems backwards is because there will be multiple clients from a household that are a client, so the address will be stored and the client's entry will have a foreign key to the appropriate address entry. John Smith address_id=1 Jane Smith address_id=1 John Anderson address_id=2.

Comment: I forgot to answer your question about street_id. My plan was to eventually build it out to where there are different tables for first name, last name, address (house number only), streets (in a different table as many clients live on the same street), city w/ zip and state. Currently street_id is just a stub and doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: `@client = Client.new` does not carry an address, so `fields_for :address` will be blank?

Comment: I got it to show the missing field by changing :address to @address.